# Laravel 5.1, Eloquent where zero value

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
$sqLines = SqLines::whereDocumentId($id)->get();
$sqLines->where('item_id','=',0)->count();
```

item_id is an unsigned integer field

In my development server, it shows result but in my production server with the record exists.
Any reason it happen?

Comment: try removing the ->get() you dont need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following

```
 $count = SqLines::where('document_id','=',$id)
 ->where('item_id','=',0)
 ->count();
```

OR

```
 $data = SqLines::where('document_id','=',$id)
 ->where('item_id','=',0)
 ->get();

 $count = count($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

With `get()`, you retrieve the result, so you can't limit it after. Change your code to this:

```
$sqLines = SqLines::whereDocumentId($id)
    ->where('item_id','=',0)
    ->get();

echo $sqlLines->count(); // wil return the number of selected records.
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will need to change your code. Use one of the following options:

- *Option 1*. Remove the "**->get()**".
- *Option 2*. Remove the "**->count()**" and add a loop for check manually the result with a "foreach", "while", etc...